# Калькулятор строк

Tags: javascript

Как сделать функцию калькулятор строк, которая принимает любое количество строк и проводит операцию если такая есть?

```
calc('3', '+', '2') === '5'

calc('6', '/', '3') === '2'

calc('2', '+', '2', '*', '2') === ‘8'
```

Я попытался перевести все в массив и создать 100 условий для каждой операции, но есть проблемы. Как это можно сделать.

```
function calc(first, ...rest) {

}
```

Comment: Вам нужен вот такой алгоритм https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8 - если посмотреть на других языках, то можно найти готовые реализации на разных языках

Comment: о, кажется понял, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
calc('(', '2', '+', '2', ')', '*', '2'); //8
function calc(...args) {
    return eval(args.join(''));
}
```

Comment: не ну если уж так писать, то мож `return eval(...args.join``)`